# How to avoid downcast in derived class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have parent class (Base) and child class (Derived). Then another interface use Base as the Generic Type and within that interface call IsDataEqual on derived objects.

That interface receives many implementations of this derived object since it use generic with type constraint to Base.

```
 public interface IMyLogic<T> where T : Base
```

Everything works fine but I feel bad about having this downcast. Is there anyway to avoid it ?

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract bool IsDataEqual(Base data);
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public string x;
    public string Y;

    public override bool IsDataEqual(Base data)
    {
        if(data.GetType() != typeof(Derived))
        {
            //Type mismatch
            throw new Exception();
        }

        Derived deriveData = data as Derived; //downcast
        
        if (this.x == deriveData.x || this.y == deriveData.y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. I can not move x and y to base class due to business logic.

Comment: Is it possible to move IsDataEqual method inside to IMyLogic<T> interface  like this 
 : public bool IsDataEqual(T t1, T t2);

Comment: @RaminRahimzada that would force whatever class that's implementing the interface to also implement the comparison between the two instances of T (which are unrelated to the interface). Doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: Well, if we dont want to write equality in every implementation of IMyLogic<T> then we  can move comparison logic into separate interface IDataEqualityLogic<T> and then inject it to the implementation class of IMyLogic<T>. The main idea here is to move the comparison logic to outside of the Base class or its future implementations

Comment: If you're going to do that, you should probably consider using [`EqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0) as your base class.

Comment: Every implementation of Base  will have a different comparison logic. Therefore I need to keep the IsDataEqual with Base.
Thanks @RaminRahimzada and Zohar

Comment: Derived derriveData = data as Derived; //downcast

This is just reference type conversion. I learned that It is not expensive as unboxing object to value type.

It just tell compiler to look at this object from different angle and there is no data conversion or anything. 

So I thought to keep my implementation as it is.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I will use `IEquatable<T>` to replace your `IsDataEqual`. I'm not sure could you change your base class or not but these is for your reference

```
public abstract class Base : IEquatable<Base>
{
    public bool Equals(Base? other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Derived : Base, IEquatable<Derived>
{
    public string x;
    public string Y;

    public bool Equals(Derived? obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this, but with this I have to implement IMyLogic for every derrived. 

public MyLogic<T> where T : Derived

Otherwise inside my logic it will use the  Public override bool Equals(object obj) instead of bool Equals(Derived? obj).

Comment: What is ```IMyLogic```? Another logic for business or it's the ```IsDataEqual```?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of comparison suggest value type semantics, so I would suggest using [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) to get value-based comparison out-of-the-box (requires c#9 or higher).

Unfortunately, though, we don't have a generic constraint for records for you to use in your interface (that would look like `public interface IMyLogic<T> where T : record`), but since records can only inherit from other records (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#inheritance)), it's enough to simply change your base type to a record (you won't need the `IsDataEqual()` abstract method anymore, but I'm assuming that's not the only reason for you to have a base class)